# Get current actor id

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management

Is it possible to get current actor's id in jBPM3?

Specifically, I need to store who initiated workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was already suggested that I can use swimlane to get the initiator.

Here, at 11.7. Swimlane in start task

http://docs.jboss.com/jbpm/v3/userguide/taskmanagement.html

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `JbpmContext.getActorId()`, depending on how you started your process.

Otherwise, you could maybe use the `TaskMgmtSesion` object to query `TaskInstance`s (associated with your process) and get the information from there?

```
String configResource = "null-or-path-to-jbpm.cfg.xml"
jbpmConfiguration jbpmConfiguration = JbpmConfiguration.getInstance(configResource);
JbpmContext jbpmContext = jbpmConfiguration.getJbpmContext();
TaskMgmtSession taskMgmtSession = jbpmContext.getTaskMgmtSession();
List taskInsts = taskMgmtSession.getfindTaskInstancesByIds(ListOfTaskInstanceIds);
// Loop over taskInsts, find correct one and retrieve actorId?
```